# How to animate like Android Emulator Loader (GLINT  Effect over Text)

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

GLINT  Effect like FLASH

I need the animation effect like Android Emulator Loader , the animation over the text ANDROID , refer the below picture . Help me out . Thanks in advance.

http://s3.amazonaws.com/files.posterous.com/temp-2011-08-22/ebCcHIdmelBnpogrgphatJeqzmBvemBlGGlCrumejaoDaxprstxpaluaxach/android-emulator-loading.PNG?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJFZAE65UYRT34AOQ&Expires=1319106995&Signature=4pgUsKCoy8gdgq2of19XVraa3to%3D

Comment: Your link gives an "Access denied" error.

Comment: Check this :    http://phandroid.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/boot-200x300.png

Answer (score 1):

as far as i know there is no built in functionality for glint effect on text in android ...
you will need to perform animation using sequence of images for your loading sign and to perform such effect the below link have complete description...

http://yekmer.posterous.com/how-to-make-a-loading-animator-in-android